# WPF Binding on multiple criterias

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, binding

In my MVVM, in view I have a DataGrid  where I want to enable the row elements based on 2 criteria.  DataGrid has checkbox in 1 col (that is bound to IsRowChecked property) and a header checkbox in another col. I want to enable the row element if 
1) IsRowChecked is true AND
2) Header checkbox is selected.

Is this multiple criteria setting possible ?

XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SiList, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="dgvSiSelection">
      <DataGrid.Columns>                  
          <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsRowChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>  
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding Header}" MinWidth="108" IsReadOnly="True"/>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Number of Chemicals" Grid.Column="0"  />
                    </Grid>                                        
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NumberOfCases}" />
                     </DataTemplate>
                     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                              <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsRowChecked}" Text="{Binding Path=NumberOfCases, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                 <!-- Value1  chkValue11-->
                 <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                     <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                          <Grid>
                              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Value1" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkValue11, Path=IsChecked}" />
                              <CheckBox Name="chkValue11"  Grid.Column="0" Width="16" />
                          </Grid>
                     </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value1}" />
                          </DataTemplate>
                     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                 <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkValue11, Path=IsChecked}" Text="{Binding Path=Value1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                  </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                  <!-- Value2  chkValue12-->
                  <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                      <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                          <Grid>
                              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                   <ColumnDefinition/>
                                   <ColumnDefinition/>
                              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Value2" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkValue12, Path=IsChecked}" />
                              <CheckBox Name="chkValue12"  Grid.Column="0" Width="16" />
                          </Grid>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value2}" />
                         </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                               <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkValue12, Path=IsChecked}" Text="{Binding Path=Value2, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                          </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

       </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

"Number of Chemicals" col need only single criteria binding which I could do. Value1 & Value2 needs 2 criteria i.e. of IsRowChecked and header checkbox selected. I could do with single, but can't get a way to implement 2 criteria's in these bindings.

How can I achieve this sort of binding ???

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There're two ways to work with complex expressions on bindings: `MultiBinding` with a converter and `MultiDataTrigger` with specific cases. For your example, both work nicely.

**1. MultiBinding**

This method works for virtually any case, but requires implementing converters (they can be reused, obviously).

1. Create `AndConverter` class implementing `IMultiValueConverter` interface. It needs to return `true` if all values passed to it are true (`DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` is a special value when value is not available).

   ```
   public class AndConverter : IMultiValueConverter
   {
       public object Convert (object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           if (values.Any(v => ReferenceEquals(v, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)))
               return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
           return values.All(System.Convert.ToBoolean);
       }

       public object[] ConvertBack (object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           throw new NotSupportedException();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add the converter to resources:

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
       <local:AndConverter x:Key="convAnd"/>
   </Window.Resources>
   ```
3. Specify `DataTemplate` for `Value1` column (original code is commented):

   ```
   <DataTemplate DataType="local:Item">
       <!--<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkValue11, Path=IsChecked}" Text="{Binding Path=Value1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>-->
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value1, Mode=TwoWay}">
           <TextBox.IsEnabled>
               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource convAnd}">
                   <Binding ElementName="chkValue11" Path="IsChecked"/>
                   <Binding Path="IsRowChecked"/>
               </MultiBinding>
           </TextBox.IsEnabled>
       </TextBox>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

**2. MultiDataTrigger**

This method works when only one property value configuration needs specific behavior. In your example, the text box is always disabled, except when *both* check boxes are checked. The syntax is more complex, but converters are not required.

1. Specify `DataTemplate` for `Value2` column (original code is commented):

   ```
   <DataTemplate DataType="local:Item">
       <!--<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkValue12, Path=IsChecked}" Text="{Binding Path=Value2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>-->
       <TextBox x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding Path=Value2, Mode=TwoWay}"
                IsEnabled="False"/>
       <DataTemplate.Triggers>
           <MultiDataTrigger>
               <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                   <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkValue12}" Value="True"/>
                   <Condition Binding="{Binding IsRowChecked}" Value="True"/>
               </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
               <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
           </MultiDataTrigger>
       </DataTemplate.Triggers>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

Comment: Wow Athari, both the options are working perfectly fine. Am wondering which one to use. In this case, I think I will go with MultiBinding only. One more question, Can I implement the same on my Header Checkboxes - If Value1 header chkbox is selected, then only let user select Value2 header checkbox. Initially Value2 header chkbox be disabled, and when user selects Value1 chkValue1, then only enable chkValue2. Can this be implemented in header checkboxes ???

Comment: @Tvd I didn't understand the exact boolean expressions, but in any case, you can use a `MultiBinding` with a converter. A `MultiBinding` can contain any number of `Binding`s, values from which are passed in a `values` argument to `IMultiValueConverter.Convert` method. Inside this method, you can write any logical expression you want. The code I've used in `Convert` is a bit complex, because it's generic and checks all possibilities, but basically it's `return (bool)values[0] && (bool)values[1]`.